# Swift / Xcode - How to clear a label when touching inside a textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am creating a simple calculator app - everything works fine but I'd like to clear the result label when the user enters a new number in a textfield (or just touches inside a textfield).

Right now I am using a touchesBegan function to clear the label (which also dismisses the keyboard:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    resultLabel.text = ""
}
```

Problem is of course that it doesn't matter where the user touches on the screen (for example accidentally doesn't hit the calc button), the label will always be cleared.

Is there a way to clear the "resultLabel" when the user touches the "numberField" textfield?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var numberField: UITextField!

 override func viewDidLoad(){
      super.viewDidLoad()
      numberField.delegate = self
 }


 extension viewcontroller: UITextFieldDelegate {
        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
            resultLabel.text = ""
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

For clear `resultlable` first thing you need to give delegate to your text filed

```
numberField.delegate = self
```

Setup your `viewcontroller` to implement `UITextFieldDelegate`

Add below method to your `viewcontroller`

```
class viewcontroller: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
   func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        resultLabel.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain in one sentence whey I have to use the delegate on the textField and set it to self?

Comment: when you set textfield.delegate = self menace UITextField class have your view controller reference, then by using your view controller reference UITextField class call method  which you have written in your viewcontroller. like textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField).

Answer (score 2):

You can use text field Delegate methods on your textField where the user is entering the numbers.

```
textField.delegate = self
textField.tag = 0
```

Add a tag to your textField and check it in didBeginEditing.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
  if textField.tag == 0 //Or whatever tag you attach{
    //Do the required task
     }
}
```